# Ionic2 menuToggle hide dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic2, and would like to show/hide the `menuToggle` on a user event. [This](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/show-side-menu-or-back-button-conditionally/16107) is how it's done in Ionic1. Does anyone know how to do it in Ionic2 please?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: update the code for your ionic menu

Answer (score 1):

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
       <button ion-button menuToggle>
         <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
       </button>
     </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Remove this HTML code from the page where you do not want to display menu-bar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your using Menu, ToggleMenu components and here is your solution

Menu bar content

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent" [enabled]="customVariable">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item menuClose detail-none>Close Menu</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

userEvent(){
    this.customVariable=false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aravind. Sorry, I may not have asked the question correctly. How do I hide the menu toggle button?  The button with the 3 stripes.

Comment: when you hide that. How you will enable it again.\

Answer (score 0):

suppose your code as following:

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent" [class.hide]="hideMenu">
 <ion-content>
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item menuClose detail-none>Close Menu</ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

then add hide style in the Component's .scss file:

```
.hide{display: none !important}
```

at last, in your .ts file, you can control the display state of menuToggle by change the value of "hideMenu", for Example,

```
hideMenu: boolean = false; // at first the menuToggle is show
....
btnClicked(){
  this.hideMenu = !this.hideMenu;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Events of 'ionic-angular' for that.

Use this code block on the user event:

```
this.events.publish("nameOfYourEvent", params)
//params => optional
```

Subscribe to the event

```
this.events.subscribe("nameOfYourEvent",(params) => {
    //toggleMenuVisibility Code goes here
    this.hideMenu = true;
})
```

On the view:

```
<button ion-button menuToggle *ngIf="!hideMenu">//[hidden] attribute is not working for some reason.
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Don't forget to import the Events class from 'ionic-angular'.

import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';